# Unable to upload image from flutter app using multipart request

Tags: android, ios, asp.net, flutter, dart

i am uploading image from mobile app flutter request send to server but no response from the server future time exception thrown, but it worked from postman.

```
    try {
      var uri = Uri.parse(NetworkRoutesController.uploadFiles);
      var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri)
        ..files.add(
          await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('File', file.path),
        );
      var response = await request.send().timeout(Duration(seconds: 30));
      if (response.statusCode == NddsSatusCodes.httpOk) {
        final res = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
        HttpResponseModel responseModel = HttpResponseModel.fromJsons(
            response.statusCode, json.decode(res.body));
        UploadPictureModel uploadPictureModel =
            UploadPictureModel.fromJson(responseModel.data[0]);
        return uploadPictureModel;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
```